# Dynamically create series in chart

Tags: c#, charts, reportviewer

I need to create a lot of series in chart in `ReportViewer`, but I can only create fixed numbers of series.
How can I create not fixed series?

Answer (score 0):

define the customdata classe

```
public class classData
{
    public String name { get; set; }

    public classData()
    {

    }
}
```

and add DataSource from VS.

preapare the list

```
List<classData> lst = new List<classData>();
```

fill list from Datatable...

```
DataRow[] result = datatable.Select();
foreach (DataRow row in result)
{
   classDatat = new classData();
   t.name = row["name"].ToString();
   last.Add(t);
}
```

pass data to report

```
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1_Customers_DataTable1", lst);
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

On report rdl

```
 <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet1_Customers_DataTable1">
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="NameFromReport">
          <DataField>name</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
    </DataSet>
 </DataSets>
```

and use NameFromReport to show data

```
<Textbox Name="textboxName">
    <rd:DefaultName>textbox1</rd:DefaultName>
    <Top>0.25cm</Top>
    <Width>8.75cm</Width>
    <Style>
      <FontFamily>Century Gothic</FontFamily>
      <FontSize>18pt</FontSize>
      <FontWeight>700</FontWeight>
      <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
      <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
      <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
      <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
    </Style>
    <ZIndex>1</ZIndex>
    <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
    <Height>1.5cm</Height>
    <Value>=NameFromReport</Value>
</Textbox>
```

End good Work!